# Права доступа на файл

Tags: права, nginx, python

На сервере python + nginx.

Python запущен от user, nginx от www-data.

На сайте есть возможность загрузить фото, кодом это изображение нарезается, и сохраняется в нужную папку. при этом оригинал сохраняется с правами 770, а новая нарезка с правами 660.
Но через сайт нельзя просмотреть ни одну из них.

Если я только в ручную меняю права на 755, тогда через сайт становятся доступны эти картинки.

Я пробовал в /etc/group добавить пользователя www-data в группу к user, надеясь что тем самым и nginx и python будут иметь общую группу, и у них будет доступ к файлам, но я ошибся.

Что я делаю не верно, от кого нужно что запускать, или какие-то настройки на сервере сделать, или еще что? Есть вариант в коде в ручную назначать права сохраняемым файлам, но ИМХО это криво, думаю должен быть выход на уровне настройки сервера.

Спасибо за внимание.